# CSS selector not working properly with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginer.I wanted to use the 'a' tags inside the 'div'in this   [html(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWmG9.jpg)

```
import requests,bs4
Main_page = requests.get('http://kissanime.to/Anime/Gintama/Episode-051?id=2437')
Gsoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(Main_page.text,'html.parser')
GG = Gsoup.select('div a')
print(len(GG))
```

Instead of 3 i get len = 0
What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Do you necessarily have to use css selector?

Otherwise you could do:

```
div = soup.find('div', id="div download")
len(div.contents)
```